# display an octal value as its string representation

Tags: python, format, octal

I've got a problem when converting an octal number to a string.

```
p = 01212
k = str(p)
print k
```

The result is `650` but I need `01212`. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your number `p` is the actual *value* rather than the *representation* of that value. So it's actually `65010`, `12128` and `28a16`, *all at the same time.*

If you want to see it as octal, just use:

```
print oct(p)
```

as per the following transcript:

```
>>> p = 01212
>>> print p
650
>>> print oct(p)
01212
```

That's for Python 2 (which you appear to be using since you use the `0NNN` variant of the octal literal rather than `0oNNN`).

Python 3 has a slightly different representation:

```
>>> p = 0o1212
>>> print (p)
650
>>> print (oct(p))
0o1212
```

Comment: In python3  there is slight modification

Comment: @Ajay, added the Py3 stuff though I believe OP is still using Py2. Still it's good to know.

Answer (score 14):

One way is to usse the `o` format character from the [Format Mini Specification Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

**Example:**

```
>>> x = 01212
>>> print "0{0:o}".format(x)
01212
```

> 'o'   Octal format. Outputs the number in base 8.

**NB:** You still have to prepend the `0` (*Unless you use the builtin function `oct()`*).

**Update:** In case you're using Python 3+:

```
$ python3.4
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 01212
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = 01212
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> x = 0o1212
>>> print(oct(x))
0o1212
>>> print("0o{0:o}".format(x))
0o1212
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, if you are using f-strings:

```
>>> p = 0o1212
>>> print(f"{p:o}")
1212
>>> print(f"{p:#o}")
0o1212
```

Note that the second notation is also available with `format`:

```
>>> print("{:#o}".format(p))
0o1212
```

But with f-strings available, this will rarely be needed.